# Pull spefic record in a $row

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to display the 2nd record in a $row.

Here is my query

```
select    LEFT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 4) Year,
      RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2) Quarter,

      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2)=03,'Enero a Marzo',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2)=06,'Abril a Junio',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2)=09,'Julio a Septiembre',
      IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2)=12,'Octubre a Diciembre',
      '')
      ))) Quarter_Name,

      ROUND(A.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Quarterly_yield

from      dr_rent_carteras_trimestres A
where     A.ID_CARTERA = $ID_CARTERA
And       A.IND_RENTABILIDAD = 1

Order by A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE asc
```

Here is the php.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $currentState = ($currentState == 'odd' ? 'even' :'odd' );


 echo "<tr id='centered' >";  echo "<td class='leftalign'>" . $row['Quarter_Name'] .     "</td>";

echo "<td>" . $row['Quarterly_yield'] . "</td>";




  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</tbody></table>";
```

I want to pull the 2nd record in Quarterly_yield.  How would I display that?

Comment: Yes, or the 3rd, 4th, Whatever the case may be.  Is there a way to specify that in the php.  Have the mysql pull all the records but have php display one at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it from PHP, you can just index your results, like you do any other array.

Alternatively, you can do this from MySQL by using LIMIT 1,1 at the end of your query.  For instance, here's your modified query.  Notice the last line:

```
select    LEFT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 4) Year,
  RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2) Quarter,
  IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2)=03,'Enero a Marzo',
  IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2)=06,'Abril a Junio',
  IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2)=09,'Julio a Septiembre',
  IF(RIGHT(A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE, 2)=12,'Octubre a Diciembre',
  '')
  ))) Quarter_Name,
  ROUND(A.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Quarterly_yield
  from      dr_rent_carteras_trimestres A
  where     A.ID_CARTERA = $ID_CARTERA
  And       A.IND_RENTABILIDAD = 1
  Order by A.F_ANOTRIMESTRE asc
  LIMIT 1,1
```

Comment: How can I specify in the php?  I still need for all the records to pull in mysql. Just can't have all of them display all at once.

Comment: Could you share how to "index your results"?

Comment: @JohnHarbert: Just do $row[1].  Remember, you're getting an array, and it can be treated like any array.  You can also find more information here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: @Tom: Yeah, I stumbled onto that one by accident.  I wouldn't have thought LIMIT could do that by the name, so that was a pleasant surprise.

Comment: Lets say I wanted the 3rd record down in $row[2]. Then what?

Comment: Well $row[2] is your 3rd record.  Remember, arrays start at 0, so $row[0] is your first record, $row[1] is your second and so on.

Comment: Let me clarify.  I need to pull the 3rd field on record 3.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20650/discussion-between-user1161318-and-john-harbert)